# What is a "freestart collision"?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, collision-resistance, terminology

In [their work on SHA-1 collisions](https://sites.google.com/site/itstheshappening/) (cf. the [EUROCRYPT-2016](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-49890-3_18) paper [*“Freestart collision on full SHA-1”* by Stevens, Karpman, and Peyrin](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/967)) Stevens et al show that they are able to generate "freestart collisions" on SHA-1. They say:

> Even though freestart collisions do not directly lead to actual collisions for SHA-1, in our case, the experimental data we obtained in the process enable significantly more accurate projections on the real-world cost of actual collisions for SHA-1, compared to previous projections.

What is a "freestart collision" on a hash function?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Definition

In the [Damgard-Merkle construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) for hash functions the compression function takes as input:

- a *message block* and
- a *chaining value*.

For the very first block there is not previous "chaining value". Instead a particular value, called an *initialisation vector* (IV) is given.

A *freestart collision* is a collision where the attacker can choose the IV.

In particular in their [paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2015/967) (page 3, Table 2-1), authors found two, slightly, different IVs (only two bits are different):

> $IV_1:$ 50 6b 01 78 ff 6d 18 **90 20** 22 91 fd 3a de 38 71 b2 c6 65 ea
>
> $IV_2:$ 50 6b 01 78 ff 6d 18 **91 a0** 22 91 fd 3a de 38 71 b2 c6 65 ea

Their attack, as they claim in their work, is the first one to break the whole 80 rounds of the SHA-1 **compression** function.

## Effect

Even if a freestart collision does not immediately give a standard collision, it could be used in multiblock collision search. The chaining value indeed is the compression function output of the previous block.

It is not clear <s>(or at least not to me)</s> how easy the path from a freestart collision to a standard collision is.
As an example: It took 8 years for MD5. The first freestart collision for MD5 was found in 1996 (Dobbertin, *[Eurocrypt Rump Session](http://www.iacr.org/conferences/ec96/rump/)*) but the first standard collision on MD5 was published only in 2004.

## Future work [Next step (from a freestart collision to a full collision)]

Finding out a freestart collision on an hash function does not break completely the function but shows a great weakness. With a freestart collision researchers exhibit *the second half* of two colliding messages. One could say that we now know how the path leading to the collision but we do not know, yet, where it starts.[image: freestartCollision]
Last step left to research is find out a block message $m_0$ which $SHA$-$1(m_0)$ is equal to the *freestart IV*.
When such message is found, the collision is served. It has to been said that finding out a message that is hashed into a given value is infeasible (it is still an hard problem for the *broken* MD5 hash function).

UPDATE: The full collision has been found: https://shattered.it/

Comment: The last sentence is a little misleading; first, the freestart collision due to Stevens et al. uses two distinct IVs, and second, finding a message that hashes to a particular number (i.e., obtaining a preimage) is likely to remain infeasible for the foreseeable future. (E.g., obtaining a preimage on MD5 is still infeasible: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/13303/is-md5-second-preimage-resistant-when-used-only-on-fixed-length-messages). Instead, research will likely progress by making it easier to find collisions without controlling the IV.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to rephrase it. Or you can also suggest an edit if you wish