# What is a 76-step SHA1 collision?

Tags: hash

From [Twitter](https://twitter.com/mik235/status/597370994655821826):

> Marc Stevens released a new 76-step (out of 80) SHA-1 collision, and SIMD libdetectcoll https://marc-stevens.nl/research/

What is a 76-step collision, and how does it differ from a "regular" collision? Is it related to whatever a "freestart" collision is?

Comment: First, read about SHA collisions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-0

Answer (score 4):

Analysis of a primitive often times is conducted on a reduced strength variant of the actual algorithm. This makes it easier to find the weak points of the design, which can become obscured after many iterations.

Assuming a "regular" collision means a collision over the entire 80 rounds, then a 76-step collision finds a collision after 76 rounds.

The [paper](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29695/29554) for the result in question does mention that it is for a free-start collision. As for what this means, [there is a Q/A here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/what-is-a-freestart-collision) that does a goob job of explaining. Basically, it means that the attacker is allowed to select the initialization vector.