Sha256: Any significance in being able to find message schedules that lead from different initial hash values but produce the same hash?
Is there any significance in being able to find message schedules that result in the same hash but require different initial hash values? Can generate every 5-10~ minutes for any hash.
Confirmed message schedule regenerates from first 16 W values, and hash produced is the same when using the new initial hash values when reconstructing. But again, I’m not sure if this is significant in any way.
Sample code of what I used to verify it’s a valid message schedule below, this matches the values I generated— all 64 values match.
for i in range(16, 64):
    w_val = (sigma1(W[i-2]) + W[i-7] + sigma0(W[i-15]) + W[i-16]) & 0xFFFFFFFF
    W.append(w_val)

Edit: This might be called a free start collision? I haven’t tried adjusting to try to match the default initial hash values for sha256.
Edit 2: Got runtime per free start collision to 10-20 seconds
Edit 3: Clarifying that the message schedules from the original message and the new message are not the same
Here are some examples:
Original Message: c6b933ebc3fc6c20efca... (Last 20 Characters Redacted)
SHA-256 Hash w/ Free Start IV: dd962f2b94954efd9bf7123d604f77964cbba3c33ebce23f5427e2bd68746b90
SHA-256 Hash w/ Default IV:    dd962f2b94954efd9bf7123d604f77964cbba3c33ebce23f5427e2bd68746b90
Free-Start IV: ['a0c713d2', 'f72d07f2', 'cae8d227', '7517016b', 'fbe4026f', 0, 0, 0] ...(Last Three Values Redacted)
Default IV:    ['6a09e667', 'bb67ae85', '3c6ef372', 'a54ff53a', '510e527f', '9b05688c', '1f83d9ab', '5be0cd19']
===========================================================================================
Processing Time: 15.410990953445435 seconds...


Original Message: c7bd47c2b2ac163413bf... (Last 20 Characters Redacted)
SHA-256 Hash w/ Free Start IV: 28fae8901514959ba91483edf61c6b68f048ba70c9c5a4f363902d203d9a5267
SHA-256 Hash w/ Default IV:    28fae8901514959ba91483edf61c6b68f048ba70c9c5a4f363902d203d9a5267
Free-Start IV: ['d04e04a6', 'a491e269', 'c9a91311', '3a6e8a91', '4ff36d8e', 0, 0, 0] ...(Last Three Values Redacted)
Default IV:    ['6a09e667', 'bb67ae85', '3c6ef372', 'a54ff53a', '510e527f', '9b05688c', '1f83d9ab', '5be0cd19']
===========================================================================================
Processing Time: 10.901056051254272 seconds...


Original Message: 6c581fe6ec7eea7cfe67... (Last 20 Characters Redacted)
SHA-256 Hash w/ Free Start IV: a3eb9a1ae2e36a2ca916641056c282ccd3591a6ccabc130da4d18f76d7b18bd9
SHA-256 Hash w/ Default IV:    a3eb9a1ae2e36a2ca916641056c282ccd3591a6ccabc130da4d18f76d7b18bd9
Free-Start IV: ['6151dac5', 'ae19c43d', '6d0ba457', '33b5ed7f', '81e3520', 0, 0, 0] ...(Last Three Values Redacted)
Default IV:    ['6a09e667', 'bb67ae85', '3c6ef372', 'a54ff53a', '510e527f', '9b05688c', '1f83d9ab', '5be0cd19']
===========================================================================================
Processing Time: 6.203358173370361 seconds...


Original Message: db6bd2b96d000a5d4727... (Last 20 Characters Redacted)
SHA-256 Hash w/ Free Start IV: ad1aad4b2a5ba77759ef3b636a0c79a5c9eb8c5b1ca34553412c3163d6abee52
SHA-256 Hash w/ Default IV:    ad1aad4b2a5ba77759ef3b636a0c79a5c9eb8c5b1ca34553412c3163d6abee52
Free-Start IV: ['dd0bdfbd', 'b509a2e5', 'd2bec68c', '89edbd89', '4f19c561', 0, 0, 0] ...(Last Three Values Redacted)
Default IV:    ['6a09e667', 'bb67ae85', '3c6ef372', 'a54ff53a', '510e527f', '9b05688c', '1f83d9ab', '5be0cd19']
===========================================================================================
Processing Time: 19.402303457260132 seconds...


Related: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/29695/what-is-a-freestart-collision

I don't quite follow what you are claiming.  Are you claiming that you can find W[0..63] values that (with an initial state) results in a target hash?  That's not very interesting.  Are you claiming that those W[0..63] values are consistent with a specific message block (W[0..15])?  That would be significant; even if it doesn't yield a specific break, it is more than is known about the SHA-256 hash compression function.

Note: In SHA-256, the message schedule is a 64×32-bit value deterministically built from a 16×32-bit message block. An alternate name can be expanded message block. As pointed by poncho, colliding message schedules are significant only if they are obtained by expansion of some message blocks.

@poncho W[0:15] generate the same W[15:63] values, they are not hand picked W values. However if you’re asking if the W[0:15] match any values in the original hash’s W[0:15] I don’t believe so, the original message and the generated messages I generate have not been checked for any shared values in their message block

IV1 and M1 and IV2 and M2 are not the same, but produce the same target hash. Expanded message block for M1 does not match expanded message block for M2. However if you expand the message block for M2, the values match the message schedule I derived from only the hash of M1.

Could you give an example of two pairs of (IV, Message Block) that result in the same hash?

Apologies, I was told by Dr. Stephens from the SHA1 paper to disclose an example privately to a professional—which is why I redacted some values in the original post, but I hope I’ve made things more clear in my last message?

I can't make sense of that statement: "if you expand the message block for M2, the values match the message schedule I derived from only the hash of M1".

Actually those values were already redacted, but that's why I said that you should at least disclose them to a professional.

Anyway, I confirmed that his attack is based on discoupling of the choice of the Davies-Meyer feedforward value and the input chaining value. It is a trivial attack, and not on the actual SHA256 compression function.

First thing to do is to make sure that what you computed is really what you think it is, and to be able to state it clearly.
Here is a perfunctory implementation of the SHA-256 hash function, that I just wrote (in Python, following the standard): https://gist.github.com/pornin/46a1701d2c2e377cf4ffe9ecb6c94b32
This implementation defines SHA256.ProcessBlock() which expects two parameters, both of type bytes (the Python type for a binary string): an initial value (32 bytes) and a message block (64 bytes). It computes and returns the 32-byte output, again with type bytes. At the end of the file there is an example of how it should be invoked.
From what you describe in your questions and comments, you claim to have something that is not, actually, a "free-start collision", but could still be interesting. First some notations: let $H$ be a hash function (here, SHA-256) which works by processing successive fixed-size blocks; processing of each block is done with the block processing function $B$ that takes two inputs (a state $s$ and a message block $m$) and produces an output (the new state value). For an input message, $H$ works as follows:

The message is padded in an unambiguous way, so that the total length of the padded message is a multiple of that of the block. In the case of SHA-256, blocks have size 64 bytes, and padding adds between 1 and 64 bytes. The padded message is then split into blocks $m_1$, $m_2$,... $m_n$.

A state value $s$ is initialized to a conventional fixed value (the IV). Then message blocks are processed one by one; for each message block, the block processing function is applied on the current state, to get the new state value, i.e. for message $i$, $s$ is replaced with $B(s, m_i)$.

The hash output is the final value of $s$.


This being given, if you can find two state values $s$ and $s'$, and two block values $m$ and $m'$, such that $B(s, m) = B(s', m')$:

If $s = s'$ and $m = m'$ then that's trivial.
If $s = s'$ and $m \neq m'$ then this is a free-start collision. It is a full collision if furthermore $s$ is the standard conventional IV.
If $s \neq s'$ then this is not what is called a free-start collision (regardless of whether $m = m'$ or $m \neq m'$); it is still interesting because intuitively this should not be easy to compute.

Take care of the following notes:

In all of the above I am talking about message blocks which are sequences of bytes (64 bytes for SHA-256). I am not talking about the expanded message, which is something internal to how SHA-256 is defined; looking at the expanded message is not relevant to knowing whether you found something that matches the description above.

What I called $B$ above is the complete block processing function. Internally, SHA-256 defines that $B$ is the combination of a complicated structure which is actually a block cipher (which uses the message block as key), and a word-wise addition (lines 89-96 in my code). The addition is important! If you forget to apply it, then it is pretty trivial to find colliding outputs, but without the addition, it's not SHA-256.

In any case, the interest here is purely "academic". This has no practical application (for attack nor for defence of anything), but it may yield some insights on how an actual attack (e.g. full collision) on SHA-256 might work. To give an historical example, on the MD5 hash function, free-start collisions were found by Dobbertin in 1996 (and he could generate them in a few minutes on a desktop computer from 1996...) while actual full collisions were found by Wang only in 2004: thus, there is no obvious and immediate path from free-start collisions to full collisions. In particular, there is no real way to monetize such finds, except in the academic way: publish the method, and possibly leverage that to get an academic job. By sending an example on ePrint (as @fgrieu suggests) you'll get attribution (i.e. nobody could "steal" your result) and that's about as much as you could hope for.


An unfortunate characteristic of the modern world is that claims by "people on the Internet" of novel properties found in standard cryptographic functions are not exactly a rarity. There are myriads of such claims and the very overwhelming majority is just a huge time-waster. This is why in practice you do not get credibility nor even attention if you do not provide something that can be independently verified -- not necessarily the method by which you get the values, but at least an example that can be fed into, for instance, a SHA-256 implementation such as mine.

Yeah what he claimed was a pseudo freestart collision (s' != s and m' != m).

But it was for the function: CFMOD(CV,M) = SHA2CAL(M,CV) + IV.

Which is a trivial attack given that SHA2CAL is invertable (for fixed M). And it has no bearing on SHA256 itself.

@Marc Stevens: Welcome to crypto-SE!! I confirm your findings above, based on test vectors and sample verification code privately communicated by the OP.

In SHA-256, the compression function has two inputs:

a 8×32-bit hash input $H$ (designated "initial hash value" or IV in the question, because that input is set to the SHA-256 Initialisation Value in the first compression function of a full SHA-256 hash)
a 16×32-bit block input $M$ (set to 512-bit of the padded message to hash)

The block $M$ is noted $W_0\ldots W_{15}$, with each of the 16 $W_i$ a 32-bit word. As part of the compression function, it is expanded into the 64×32-bit message schedule $W_0\ldots W_{63}$ with $W_0\ldots W_{15}$ unchanged, as shown in the question.

Is there any significance in being able to find message schedules that result in the same hash but require different initial hash values?

Only for message schedules that could occur in SHA-256, that is such that their $W_{16}\ldots W_{63}$ are as computed from their $W_0\ldots W_{15}$ by the standard method. This seems to be the meaning of the question's "it’s a valid message schedule", but the question does not contain enough to check the assertion made.
Assuming that, it's better to state the result not in term of message schedule, but in term of message blocks: the questions asserts producing distinct pairs $(H_0,M_0)$ and $(H_1,M_1)$ that yield the same output for the SHA-256 compression function. That is, a collision for the SHA-256 compression function (but not a free-start collision, which additionally requires $H_0=H_1$).
I think this would be a publishable result. At least, the first published collision for the compression function of MD5 was not a free-start collision, yet was a major milestone in attacking that hash. It is highly cited: Bert den Boer & Antoon Bosselaers, Collisions for the compression function of MD5, in proceedings of Crypto 1993.
Ideally, the OP would post here an example of $(H_0,M_0)$ and $(H_1,M_1)$. That's a mere 384 hexadecimal characters (plus formatting). Or at least send that to a trusted person able to independently confirm the result.
Then if the result is confirmed, possible next steps are pre-publication of the method at ePrint, and/or submission to an IACR conference (Update: but see below !)

A comment suggests the SHA-256 compression function might have been modified to use two different values for the hash input: one used to initialize the 32-byte state, the other at the end to obtain the result with eight 32-bit additions. Because the SHA-256 round function uses the Davies-Meyer structure, it's easy to modify the value of either one of these now two 32-byte inputs to obtain any desired output value. That, and direct consequences, are void of interest.
Update: I was privately given test values and verification code in Python. Just as Marc Stevens first reported, I found that the standard SHA-256 IV remains used at the end of the code for the SHA-256 function. This confirms the above beyond doubt.

I didn’t take message padding into account, the last 20ish bits of the padded form of M2 will always be wrong =‘), so the message schedule is invalid. Tried to generate the message and it kept creating another message chunk and I couldn’t figure out why for a while.

@Leo Costa: In my answer, $M$ can take any 512-bit value. Only the last $M$ in a full SHA-256 hash is constrained by message padding, and if collisions could be obtained for SHA-256 modified by disregarding message padding, and the colliding messages are of equal number of blocks, then we could get SHA-256 collision. Thus not taking message padding into account is a non-issue. The two main issues with the question's claim are that it is stated in term of message schedule for no good reason, and that information allowing the claim to be independently verified is (purposely) withheld.

“Only for message schedules that could occur in SHA-256, that is such that their W16…W63 are as computed from their W0…W15 by the standard method” — Yes this is correct, the 512-bit (64 byte) message schedule generated results in the same hash only if it is not padded (all messages must be padded exceeding 440 bits) and if the initial values are the values provided, not the standard initial values. The collision is of the resulting hash.

Relieving if true that there is still significance even if the hash is the same only before the next block is processed (created from padding). I was going to throw it in but will show Dr. Stephens to verify

@Leo Costa: All SHA-256 messages get padded, irrespective of size. The only message block that's padded is the last one in the SHA-256 hash. You should be able to test your conjecture yourself using the python class linked in Thomas Pornin's answer, with like print(SHA256.ProcessBlock(IV0, M0)==SHA256.ProcessBlock(IV1, M1) and M0!=M1), where IV0/IV1 are your two 16-byte IVs, and M0/M1 are your two 32-byte messages (equivalently the first 32 bytes of your 256-byte key schedules). If that's true (resp. false), your assertion is confirmed (resp. disproved).

I tried using it with IVO and M1 and it gave me a different hash? Perhaps I’m using it incorrectly.

IV = bytes.fromhex('6a09e667bb67ae853c6ef372a54ff53a510e527f9b05688c1f83d9ab5be0cd19')
Mb = bytes.fromhex('6d5e3d60442ce6503675f4c53b11260f8a3986e85ba6afa0088b91a8360a14878000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100')
print(SHA256.ProcessBlock(IV, Mb).hex()) Hash output should be 401704d1a8d61e233414b469c7214bcc82880571aa58431b879642ef8949ee8c but thats not what I received from their code, the original message was: a904e293c7c5017ef9462d04e83afdd9b33e4bd30521e292a228b66289c96356

@Leo Costa: The 32-byte message 6d5e3d60442ce6503675f4c53b11260f8a3986e85ba6afa0088b91a8360a1487 (not a904e293c7c5017ef9462d04e83afdd9b33e4bd30521e292a228b66289c96356) gives the padded message block 6d5e3d60442ce6503675f4c53b11260f8a3986e85ba6afa0088b91a8360a14878000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100 in your test. Feeding the SHA-256 IV and that message block to Thomas Pornin's ProcessBlock yields abe86af37ea3d869eb496a87905878a4c879ec5a333102b1d033e9b6a6e65de8, which indeed is the SHA-256 of the 32-byte message.

@Leo Costa: And your 32-byte message a904e293c7c5017ef9462d04e83afdd9b33e4bd30521e292a228b66289c96356 indeed hashes to 401704d1a8d61e233414b469c7214bcc82880571aa58431b879642ef8949ee8c, but gives the padded message block a904e293c7c5017ef9462d04e83afdd9b33e4bd30521e292a228b66289c963568000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100 (not your 6d5e3d60442ce6503675f4c53b11260f8a3986e85ba6afa0088b91a8360a14878000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100). Seems you got the structure of SHA-256 wrong.

Does this use the same IV at the beginning and end of the process? My “freestart collision” uses a different IV1 and then the original IV0 afterwards for M1 to produce the same hash.

@LeoCosta: Yes the SHA-256 compression function, that Thomas Pornin or I discussed, uses the same 32-byte hash input (the one that's set to the SHA-256 IV for messages up to 55 bytes) twice: to initialize the 32-byte hash state in the compression function, and at the end to produce the SHA-256 hash output with 32-bit additions. If the SHA-256 compression function is modified to not use the same value at these two steps, it's no longer the SHA-256 compression function, and it has an extra input. You won't get people interested in studying collisions obtained by changing that extra input.

@LeoCosta: after examining your code, I conclude that at lines 239..248 it uses the standard IV of SHA-256, thus that your collisions (which do occur with your code, that I ran after removing a dependency to mpmath) are for a modified SHA-256 round function, where the values added at the end of a SHA-256 round are from that standard IV, rather than from the 32-byte hash input (your free_start_initial_values). This is what I discuss in the above comment. Marc Stevens independently reached the same conclusion.

For kicks, what would be something I should strive for next—trying to use the same IVs for the beginning and end of the function (instead of just the beginning, and then the standard IV values for the end) so it isn’t modified? Actually I feel like I could already do that, I just apply the same IV2 at the end as I do in the beginning, I believe I accidentally used the default IV to redeem the final strings instead of the IV2 I generate. I’ll try when I get home. Would that be significant if successful?

@Leo Costa: Yes, IF you managed to get collisions for the unmodified SHA-256 round function, even if the two 32-byte hash inputs and the two 64-byte messages are arbitrary, then (as I wrote in the first section of the answer) that would I believe be of academic interest. That's even though there is no obvious path from that to full SHA-256 collision. Attacks get improved! But you'll find that such collision for the actual round function are much harder to achieve than what you describe.

Ahh, I get it— it’s not so trivial trying to apply the IV at both ends, as a starting point and near the ending point.
